# Android lock screen behaviour

Tags: android, oncreate, lockscreen

If I press home and come back to my app a little later I will find that the state has been preserved perfectly. For some reason however if I lock the phone and then unlock it, my app has been returned to the original state bar a few things here and there. When I looked into the logs I found that onCreate had been called while the phone was in a locked state. Because locking the phone is quite an off hand thing to do, having your game reset every time you do so is not desirable to the user. How can this be avoided at least for a longer period of time than a few seconds after locking the phone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how Android OS works, it decides by it's own when to destroy your view. To avoid loosing this information there is a Method that can be reimplemented in your activity

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState){
    iGameContent.saveGame(outState);
}
```

Save all your needed data into outState, and in the onCreate method, check if its a new instance or saved instance, like this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.game);

    if (savedInstanceState!=null){
        iGameContent.loadGame(savedInstanceState);
    }else{
        // Normal initialization
    }
}
```

An example of the save/load to a Bundle is the following:

```
public void loadGame(Bundle aBundle){
    iBadsHit = aBundle.getInt("iBadsHits",0);
}

public void saveGame(Bundle aBundle){
aBundle.putInt("iBadsHit", iBadsHit);
}
```

Comment: Are we talking about long term saves(eg: highscores) or short term (eg: last level played)?

Comment: No, short term. If you close your app, the bundle is cleared. onSavedInstanceState it's there to seem like the system hasn't killed the app

Comment: Just write all the variables of the class in this bundle, and it will be restored when coming from background or changing orientation. But not when starting the app

Comment: long term stuff should be saved during the game or when finishing a level using SharedPreferences class

Answer (score 1):

If your log is showing that onCreate has been called then that means your apps process was killed.

Do you know the Android Activity Lifecycle? If not, read up on it here: [Android Activities](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)

Comment: Yes I guess that much, but i'm a bit confused as to why the phone kills my process on lock screen consistently but not (so much) when the phone is still being used for other things. Also the splash screen does not show again so the process can't have been completely killed

Comment: Also its odd that you can press home and then lock and the state will be perfectly preserved.

Comment: So it hasn't been killed. I would guess that your game is in landscape orientation then, right? If so, you just need to persist the game state as described in the link in my answer. You should be doing this anyway though if you don't want the user pressing Home to restart the game when they next launch it.

Comment: Oh does forcing a portrait orientation crap out the process?

Comment: Orientation changes will cause the Activity to be created again.

Comment: ah bum! Does the bundle ever get trashed?

Answer (score 0):

The behavior on screen lock could vary from one device to other. Some events could cause the destruction of the app. You can try to handle some of this events to avoid this situation specifying it on the AndroidManifest.xml:

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
```

These two are the most problematic in screen lock. Yo can find more information on the last chapter of this [nvidia document](https://developer.nvidia.com/sites/default/files/akamai/mobile/docs/android_lifecycle_app_note.pdf)